# Use Materialized View or Normal View in this case?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle11g, materialized-views

Base on some research it seems `AGGREGATION` cannot use `FAST FRESH` in Materialized View?

I find a piece of [oracle document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10706/repmview.htm#BABEEHGJ) states that a `Complex Materialized View` cannot be fast refreshed.

```
In some cases, an aggregate function, although it is possible to have an aggregate 
function in the defining query and still have a simple materialized view.
For example, the following statement creates a complex materialized view:

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW hr.average_sal AS
SELECT AVG(salary) "Average" FROM hr.employees@orc1.example.com;
```

The materialized view I am creating include `SUM()` aggregation for a result of multiple joins(6 six joins should return some `8 thousand` rows). the view should refresh every 20 seconds. 
here is the script

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW V_MVIEW$BASEVIEW
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST START WITH (sysdate) NEXT (sysdate+1*20/(60*60*24)) WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS
    select 
        cb.id as cb_id,
        vb.id as vb_id,
        sb.id as sb_id,
        v.id as v_id, v.name as v_name,
        t.t1 as t1, t.t2 as t2, t.t3 as t3,
        c.id,
        SUM(t.amount) as t_amount

        from t
            join cb on t.cb_id = cb.id
            join vb on cb.vb_id = vb.id
            join sb on sb.id = vb.sb_id
            join v on v.id = sb.v_id
            join c on c.id=cb.c_id

        GROUP BY 
            cb.id, 
            vb.id, 
            sb.id, 
            v.id, v.name, 
            t.t1, t.t2, t.t3, 
            c.id
            ;
```

With above constraints I am not quite sure it still even beneficial to use materialized view any more, because refresh the whole view for every 20 second may be no better than normal views? How can I optimize the situation?

Comment: Refresh every 20 seconds?  That seems a bit counter-intuative...if the run time on this script is more than 10 seconds, then you have your server spending half it's day processing this.  If it's under 10 seconds, maybe a materialized view isn't the way to go?  What benefit does your business gain if it's data is refreshed every 20 seconds instead of every minute or 2?

Comment: @Twelfth Thank you. the query takes about less one seconds to return all results, but we need it repeat every 20 seconds to get the most recent result. the reason we prefer to use views is to minimize I/O to avoid transaction issues on read-only data. Also there could be other views join this base view, they wont take more than several seconds to return result, but still need to refresh every 10-30 seconds.

Comment: How many times is this materialized view being called?  If it's getting used some 50 times a minute...I think it makes sense.  And I guess as a second question, are your indexes good and being fully used on this?

Comment: @Twelfth It could be called less than 10 times from the UI, I am not planning to create indexes on those M views, but all the joins within the mviews are pretty much made by primary keys and foreign key which are properly indexed(at least Oracle SQL adviser has no further advice to the m view quereis).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience materialized views are used for situations where the receiving server cannot be without the data if the host system is unavailable.  I agree with the comments above that refreshing every 20 seconds seems excessive, but if that's what the data does then that's what the data does.

For example, lets say we have an order entry system and an inventory control system.  The inventory control system maintains a status of the inventory (good, expired, damaged, etc).  The order entry system needs to know how much good inventory it has to take orders.  This would be a good case for a materialized view, because the inventory status information is critical to the order entry process.  Without it, the order entry system would not be able to take orders because it couldn't check the statuses.

However, on the other side.  Let's say the same order entry system generates an inventory report that includes inventory in the distribution center, and inventory on order.  The distribution center doesn't know about the orders, so lets just agree that the order entry system is the right place to generate this report.  If we can't generate the report, managers may grumble, but it won't stop business.  This would be a good case for a standard view across a dblink.  The use of the data isn't critical so if the inventory control system is down for some reason, it's not a big deal because the order entry system can just run the report later.

Sorry if I haven't really answered your question, but hopefully it gives you something to think about.

Comment: Thanks, I can see the wisdom from your post. Is the "standard view" mentioned in your post means the normal non-materiazlied view? The intention to introduce m view in my project is only to avoid performance overhead. Losing the data from normal view is not an issue. As data from master table is safe, it is all good. It is just not sure about refresh the query with six table join together every 20 second with 10 thousands record will cause oracle go crazy(let's just assume the database is properly assign with necessary resources).